# Retrieve all properties in CamelContext

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I'm writing a bean that extends `LifecycleStrategy` and during

```
onContextStart(CamelContext context)
```

I need to retrieve all the properties that have been loaded in the context. If I call `context.getProperties()` it returns a map with lenght = 0 (it seams that no properties are loaded) but if i call `resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{one.of.my.properties}}")` it resolves correctly.. There is any way to retrieve all the properties key?

ps. my properties are loaded via propertyPlaceholder in camelContext

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problematic and the only way to do it was to read again the property file from the context:

```
PropertiesComponent pc = (PropertiesComponent) exchange
                            .getContext()
                            .getComponent("properties");

// Assume only one property file configured
String location = pc.getLocations()[0];

Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(getClass()
        .getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream(
                StringUtils.substringAfter(location,
                        ":"))); // remove the classpath: if existing

for (String propName : props.stringPropertyNames()) {

    if (propName.startsWith("my.word.")) {
        endpoints.add(props.getProperty(propName));
    }
}
```

I don't think it is nice way, but for the moment I have no other cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different things.

context.getProperties() is some options you can configure.

The other thing is property placeholder
http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: Thanks! but what is the way to retrieve all the properties I have declared in property placeholder in the camel context?

Comment: propertyPlaceholders does not supports wildcards so far as I know. E.g get all properties starting with some word: `{{my.word.*}}` then the question is still open to me as well

Comment: Build your own properties parser and set it on the properties component, then you can trap all lookup calls, and delegate to the default that does the actual lookup - org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesParser

Comment: Easy to say, but I am using BlueprintPropertyResolver/Parser and it is difficult to find a real example. Any links?